# Can I use an ELV dimmer to dim an electronic switching power supply for LEDs

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, dimming

I am using a Meanwell 350-12 power supply to power LED light strips which use SMD 5050 diodes. It is an electronic switching power supply. The strips use PWM normally to accomplish dimming.

In this application I would like to use a Lutron DVELV 600 dimmer to dim the LEDs. Will it work or will it destroy the power supply and LEDs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doubt it. From the datasheet/installation guide:

> Blockquote 1. CAUTION:To avoid overheating and possible damage to other equipment,
>   do not use to control receptacles, fluorescent lighting fixtures, motor-operated or transformer-supplied appliances.
>   2. Use only to control the primary side of electronic transformer-supplied
>   low-voltage lighting, or in combination with incandescent lamps.
>   3. This product requires a neutral wire in the wallbox.
>   Blockquote

At some point you may reduce voltage to the LEDs such that they dim or just go out.  I do not know if this will damage your LED strip.  I would investigate this: [TLC5940](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TLC5940NT/296-17732-5-ND/716896) which is a PWM controller for LEDs.  It is ~ $4.20 vs. $70.00 USD and while it may require some external componenets it will be a superior and less expensive option.